# Flowers sent by the birds

Tags: species-identification, botany

Birds have sown seeds on my ground and this beautiful flower has sprung.  What's the name of this flower?

I live in Sao Paulo, Brazil

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a type of [begonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begonia). With 1800 species in the genus, it's hard to say which it is, but the leaves which seem palmate would place it in the [aconitifolia](https://worldoffloweringplants.com/begonia-aconitifolia-cane-begonia/) species. Your leaves don't appear to be variegated, and your flower is deeper pink, but it's the same flower species.

[image]  [image]